# Overriding necessary to avoid runtime type check for Java generic method?

Tags: java, generics

The following snippet of generic magic has saved me some grief by caching very expensive functions on Strings (which Phrase simply wraps).

```java
public class Phrase {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<Function<? extends Phrase, ?>, Object> memos;
    public final String text;
    public <X, T extends Phrase> X memo(Function<T, X> app) {
        return (X) memos.computeIfAbsent(app, unused -> app.apply((T) this));
    }
}
// Example follows
public class Joke extends Phrase {
    boolean isoffcolor;
}
public class BigramJokeEvaluator {
    public Boolean static isFunny(Joke joke) {
        return !joke.isoffcolor;
    }
}
public class MilesAway {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Boom
        new Phrase("Moo goes the cow!").memo(BigramJokeEvaluator::isFunny);
    }
}
```

I have several subclasses of Phrase, with their own respective functions, and when other modules use subclasses of Phrase along with those functions, it's up to the programmer to make sure type `T` of `T extends Phrase` lines up correctly.

Function<>'s are immutable so the runtime coercion of `(X)` is guaranteed. But if I want to make the coercion of `T` into a compile-time type check:

- Is there some way I can forward the lower function's type constraint to the higher-level function's type constraint? (Effectively making memo in the case of Joke as if it was `<X> X memo(Function<Joke, X>);`) [Does Type Erasure prevent this?]
- Do I have to make delegate functions in all the subclasses of Phrase?
- Is there some trick other than 'just not making any mistakes'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you can do is this:

```
public class Phrase<P extends Phrase<P>> {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<Function<P, ?>, Object> memos;
    public final String text;
    public <X> X memo(Function<P, X> app) {
        return (X) memos.computeIfAbsent(app, unused -> app.apply((P) this));
    }
}

class Joke extends Phrase<Joke> {...}
```

This is called [F-bounded quantification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification) and it's used by e.g. [`Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

It's a bit of a pain in the neck but it generally works.

Note that it does not guarantee that `P` is the type of `this`:

```
class Joke extends Phrase<Joke> {}
// oops
class Troll extends Phrase<Joke> {}
```

It's also impossible to capture a `Class<? extends Phrase<?>>`:

```
{
    Class<? extends Phrase<?>> j = Joke.class;
    m( j ); // fails, but would pass if P was not F-bounded
}
static <P extends Phrase<P>> void m(Class<P> c) {}
```

But overall, it makes it harder to make the more likely types of mistakes.

> Do I have to make delegate functions in all the subclasses of Phrase?

Delegating to subclasses is difficult because of 1. no covariant parameters and 2. erasure.

```
class Phrase {
    ...
    <X> X memo(Function<Phrase, X> f) {...}
}

class Joke extends Phrase {
    ...
    // this is a compiler error
    // (technically, I think it's classified as
    // "override-equivalent", but specified to fail)
    <X> X memo(Function<Joke, X> f) {...}
}
```

(If that's the type of thing you're referring to by 'delegate'. Otherwise, feel free to clarify.)

You *could* delegate with a type parameter e.g.:

```
class Phrase<P> {
    abstract <X> X memo(Function<P, X> f);
}
class Joke extends Phrase<Joke> {
    @Override
    <X> X memo(Function<Joke, X> f) {...}
}
```

This avoids the unchecked casting.

Comment: The bound on `P` is unused -- `public class Phrase<P>` would compile the same

Answer (score 0):

You should make a type parameter (here we call `P`) to represent the type of the subclass, and then for the method that cares about the relationship of `P` to its type parameter, we use a generic method to do it (it's static so it's "outside" the class):

```
class Phrase<P> {
    final HashMap<Function<P, ?>, Object> memos = new HashMap<>();
    public static <X, T extends Phrase<T>> X memo(T phrase, Function<T, X> app) {
        return (X) phrase.memos.computeIfAbsent(app, unused -> app.apply(phrase));
    }
}

Phrase.memo(new Phrase(), BigramJokeEvaluator::isFunny);
```